# Issue with Open Json returning null

Tags: json, sql-server-2016

I have a JSON structured like this:

```
{
"Assessment": {
    "AssessmentContext": {
        "ReportID": "1021060",
        "ReportName": "John Smith",
    },
}
```

I am using SQL server 2016 and this is my query:

```
SELECT Data.ReportID,Data.ReportName
FROM TableName DT
CROSS APPLY 
OPENJSON(DT.TX_TEXT) WITH (
ReportID INT '$.ReportID',
ReportName VARCHAR(100) '$.ReportName'
    ) AS Data
```

I am getting NULL values for both the columns when I run this query. What am I doing wrong?

Update:

I am editing the question as I am not able to format the text as code in comment. How do I tweak my sql to show Report Id, Report Name, Item Name, Value.

```
{
  "Assessment": {
"AssessmentContext": {
    "ReportID": "1021060",
    "ReportName": "John Smith",
},
},       

"Assessment": {
        "AssessmentID": "0",
        "AssessmentItems": [{
                "ItemName": "A",
                "Value": "N"                    
            }, {
                "ItemName": "B",
                "Value": "A"                    
            }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass path:

```
SELECT Data.ReportID,Data.ReportName
FROM TableName DT
CROSS APPLY 
OPENJSON(DT.TX_TEXT, '$.Assessment.AssessmentContext') -- here
WITH ( ReportID INT '$.ReportID',
       ReportName VARCHAR(100) '$.ReportName') AS Data
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bb4573b2dba489f7d0b270073381946f)**

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked. Never knew it was so simple duh.